# get pure text form odt file in console

Tags: text, console, openoffice-writer, format-conversion

I am looking for a small linux tool that would be able to extract text from odt file.
It just needs to be human-readable and it can have problems with complicated objects etc.

It's almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564153/convert-odt-doc-ods-files-to-txt-files) but I need it to be small and have no dependencies on OpenOffice or X server

I remember having a 1MB MS-DOS program that could render .doc files quite readibly (with some weird markup getting through from time to time), so i expect it to be possible in the linux world too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always find them just after asking in public...

[odt2txt](http://packages.debian.org/sid/odt2txt) - avaliable in repos.

I feel stupid :P